# Compare two DataFrames and filter items only listed in the second

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have two pandas DataFrames and I would like to filter out items that are only listed in the second one. It's similar to a merge, then drop_duplicates but with the twist that it should after that also delete all items in the first table.

The result is only items that are listed in the second DataFrame but not in the first. I will also need a subset (as provided in drop_duplicates) to determine which ones are listed in both.

Or to rephrase it: take DataFrame2 and remove all items that are listed in DataFrames1, based on certain columns.

Comment: Can you post representative data, both dfs and desired output, it sounds like what you want to do is `df[df['col'].isin(df1['col'])]` or similar

Comment: Also won't `df.merge(df1)` just work in your case? if the column to check against is named the same?

Comment: I think I want the opposite. Basically I want dF2 and remove all times in it that are mentioned in df1

Comment: so something like `df1[~df1['col'].isin[df['col]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

```
print df1
#   age name
#0   22  foo
#1   50  bar
#2   70  aaa
print df2
#   age name
#0   22  foo
#1   80  ccc
#2   50  bar
#3   30  baz
#4   10  bar
#5   40  bbb

#filter data for equal rows of both dataframes
df3 = df2[df2['name'].isin(df1['name']) & df2['age'].isin(df1['age'])]
print df3
#   age name
#0   22  foo
#2   50  bar
#filter data of df2 which are not in df1
df4 = df2[~df2['name'].isin(df1['name']) | ~df2['age'].isin(df1['age'])]
print df4
#   age name
#1   80  ccc
#3   30  baz
#4   10  bar
#5   40  bbb
```

Comment: This only shows that the elements match, not that the row matches.  You need to show where any row in df2 matches the row in df1.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, although it's admittedly a litte heavy-handed. Still, you can define any number of columns you want in the `on` argument to `merge` (provided the columns are in both data sets, of course).

```
# Rows that are in this df should be removed from df2
# The first two rows are in both dfs, the third isn't.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'bak'],
    'age': [22, 50, 30]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bar'],
    'age': [22, 50, 30, 10]
})
df1['is_in_first_df'] = True

# Select the necessary columns and merge both dfs using an outer join
# so that rows that are in df2 but not df1 aren't lost.
df2_ = pd.merge(df2, df1, on=['age', 'name'], how='outer').fillna(False)

# Now just remove all those rows from df2 and remove the flag column
df2_[~df2_.is_in_first_df].drop('is_in_first_col', axis=1)
```