# Compare two dataframes and create a new one

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have two dataframes `certdf` and `df` that I have compared using:

```
certdf['SampNum'].isin(df['SampNum']).value_counts()
```

resulting in:

```
True     730
False    170
Name: SampNum, dtype: int64
```

I want to export the 170 rows from `certdf` that are not present in `df` into their own dataframe. Eventually I will simply add these values to `df`, but I also need to export them as an independant xlsx file. My thought was that if I can get the values as an independant dataframe, I can use `ExcelWriter` to spit out my file.  I'm new to python, but not to scripting, so I know this is probably really simple, but I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: `two_dataframe_dict = {k: d for k, d in certdf.groupby(certdf.SampNum.isin(df.SampNum))}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036804/compare-two-dataframes-and-filter-items-only-listed-in-the-second

Comment: Merge left excluding join in [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: thanks everyone.  i feel a little silly, actually.  this worked perfectly: `diffdf = certdf[~certdf['SampNum'].isin(df['SampNum'])]`